# Photoshop ScriptListener to access all files in folder

Tags: javascript, actionscript, photoshop

I've just made an action script with ScriptListener plugin in Photoshop cc. I don't know javascript. Can you help me to write some code, that will help me to access all files in source folder, then after applying photoshop filter save them in folder with their names. 
P.S. Sorry for my English.

```
// =======================================================
var idOpn = charIDToTypeID( "Opn " );
var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
desc1.putPath( idnull, new File( "C:\\Users\\Данила\\Documents\\PhotoBook\\DSCF1698.JPG"    ) );
executeAction( idOpn, desc1, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idCnvM = charIDToTypeID( "CnvM" );
var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
var idGrys = charIDToTypeID( "Grys" );
desc2.putClass( idT, idGrys );
executeAction( idCnvM, desc2, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idHghP = charIDToTypeID( "HghP" );
var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idRds = charIDToTypeID( "Rds " );
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
desc3.putUnitDouble( idRds, idPxl, 9.200000 );
executeAction( idHghP, desc3, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idLvls = charIDToTypeID( "Lvls" );
var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idpresetKind = stringIDToTypeID( "presetKind" );
var idpresetKindType = stringIDToTypeID( "presetKindType" );
var idpresetKindCustom = stringIDToTypeID( "presetKindCustom" );
desc4.putEnumerated( idpresetKind, idpresetKindType, idpresetKindCustom );
var idAdjs = charIDToTypeID( "Adjs" );
    var list1 = new ActionList();
        var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
            var ref1 = new ActionReference();
            var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
            var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
            var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
            ref1.putEnumerated( idChnl, idOrdn, idTrgt );
        desc5.putReference( idChnl, ref1 );
        var idInpt = charIDToTypeID( "Inpt" );
            var list2 = new ActionList();
            list2.putInteger( 100 );
            list2.putInteger( 125 );
        desc5.putList( idInpt, list2 );
        var idGmm = charIDToTypeID( "Gmm " );
        desc5.putDouble( idGmm, 0.800000 );
    var idLvlA = charIDToTypeID( "LvlA" );
    list1.putObject( idLvlA, desc5 );
desc4.putList( idAdjs, list1 );
executeAction( idLvls, desc4, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref2 = new ActionReference();
    var idmoveTool = stringIDToTypeID( "moveTool" );
    ref2.putClass( idmoveTool );
desc6.putReference( idnull, ref2 );
var iddontRecord = stringIDToTypeID( "dontRecord" );
desc6.putBoolean( iddontRecord, true );
var idforceNotify = stringIDToTypeID( "forceNotify" );
desc6.putBoolean( idforceNotify, true );
executeAction( idslct, desc6, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idsave = charIDToTypeID( "save" );
var desc7 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idAs = charIDToTypeID( "As  " );
    var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idEQlt = charIDToTypeID( "EQlt" );
    desc8.putInteger( idEQlt, 12 );
    var idMttC = charIDToTypeID( "MttC" );
    var idMttC = charIDToTypeID( "MttC" );
    var idNone = charIDToTypeID( "None" );
    desc8.putEnumerated( idMttC, idMttC, idNone );
var idJPEG = charIDToTypeID( "JPEG" );
desc7.putObject( idAs, idJPEG, desc8 );
var idIn = charIDToTypeID( "In  " );
desc7.putPath( idIn, new File( "C:\\Users\\Данила\\Desktop\\Photobook\\DSCF1698.jpg" ) );
var idDocI = charIDToTypeID( "DocI" );
desc7.putInteger( idDocI, 35 );
var idsaveStage = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStage" );
var idsaveStageType = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStageType" );
var idsaveBegin = stringIDToTypeID( "saveBegin" );
desc7.putEnumerated( idsaveStage, idsaveStageType, idsaveBegin );
executeAction( idsave, desc7, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idsave = charIDToTypeID( "save" );
var desc9 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idAs = charIDToTypeID( "As  " );
    var desc10 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idEQlt = charIDToTypeID( "EQlt" );
    desc10.putInteger( idEQlt, 12 );
    var idMttC = charIDToTypeID( "MttC" );
    var idMttC = charIDToTypeID( "MttC" );
    var idNone = charIDToTypeID( "None" );
    desc10.putEnumerated( idMttC, idMttC, idNone );
var idJPEG = charIDToTypeID( "JPEG" );
desc9.putObject( idAs, idJPEG, desc10 );
var idIn = charIDToTypeID( "In  " );
desc9.putPath( idIn, new File( "C:\\Users\\Данила\\Desktop\\Photobook\\DSCF1698.jpg" ) );
var idDocI = charIDToTypeID( "DocI" );
desc9.putInteger( idDocI, 35 );
var idsaveStage = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStage" );
var idsaveStageType = stringIDToTypeID( "saveStageType" );
var idsaveSucceeded = stringIDToTypeID( "saveSucceeded" );
desc9.putEnumerated( idsaveStage, idsaveStageType, idsaveSucceeded );
executeAction( idsave, desc9, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idCls = charIDToTypeID( "Cls " );
executeAction( idCls, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. I've wrapped up the main process in a function called doStuff and then it saves & closes the file. Note! It will overwite existing files, so keep a back-up of your source files first!

```
//pref pixels
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

var myJpgQuality = 12; // jpeg quality

// get all the files to process
var inFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Please select folder to process");
if (inFolder != null)
{
    var fileList = inFolder.getFiles();
}

// look over the first image
var indexFile = fileList[0].toString();
var myDirectoryName = indexFile.substring(0, indexFile.lastIndexOf("/"));

for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
{

    try 
    {
      var doc = open(fileList[i]);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      alert("Failed to open!");
    }

    var myFile = fileList[i].toString();
    var myFileName = myFile.substring(myFile.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, myFile.lastIndexOf("."));
    var myFilePath = myDirectoryName + "/" + myFileName + ".jpg";

    // run the main function here
    doStuff();

    // save
    saveAsJpeg(myFilePath);

    //close without saving
    app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}

function saveAsJpeg(apath)
{
    // jpg file options
    var jpgFile = new File(apath);
    jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
    jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
    jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
    jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
    jpgSaveOptions.quality = myJpgQuality;

    activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}


function doStuff()
{
    // =======================================================
    var idCnvM = charIDToTypeID( "CnvM" );
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var idGrys = charIDToTypeID( "Grys" );
    desc2.putClass( idT, idGrys );
    executeAction( idCnvM, desc2, DialogModes.NO );

    // =======================================================
    var idHghP = charIDToTypeID( "HghP" );
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idRds = charIDToTypeID( "Rds " );
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc3.putUnitDouble( idRds, idPxl, 9.200000 );
    executeAction( idHghP, desc3, DialogModes.NO );

    // =======================================================
    var idLvls = charIDToTypeID( "Lvls" );
    var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idpresetKind = stringIDToTypeID( "presetKind" );
    var idpresetKindType = stringIDToTypeID( "presetKindType" );
    var idpresetKindCustom = stringIDToTypeID( "presetKindCustom" );
    desc4.putEnumerated( idpresetKind, idpresetKindType, idpresetKindCustom );
    var idAdjs = charIDToTypeID( "Adjs" );
        var list1 = new ActionList();
            var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
            var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
                var ref1 = new ActionReference();
                var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
                var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
                var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
                ref1.putEnumerated( idChnl, idOrdn, idTrgt );
            desc5.putReference( idChnl, ref1 );
            var idInpt = charIDToTypeID( "Inpt" );
                var list2 = new ActionList();
                list2.putInteger( 100 );
                list2.putInteger( 125 );
            desc5.putList( idInpt, list2 );
            var idGmm = charIDToTypeID( "Gmm " );
            desc5.putDouble( idGmm, 0.800000 );
        var idLvlA = charIDToTypeID( "LvlA" );
        list1.putObject( idLvlA, desc5 );
    desc4.putList( idAdjs, list1 );
    executeAction( idLvls, desc4, DialogModes.NO );

    // =======================================================
    var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
    var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref2 = new ActionReference();
        var idmoveTool = stringIDToTypeID( "moveTool" );
        ref2.putClass( idmoveTool );
    desc6.putReference( idnull, ref2 );
    var iddontRecord = stringIDToTypeID( "dontRecord" );
    desc6.putBoolean( iddontRecord, true );
    var idforceNotify = stringIDToTypeID( "forceNotify" );
    desc6.putBoolean( idforceNotify, true );
    executeAction( idslct, desc6, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm also do it, but no so pretty as you. I add this:
    `\nvar inputFolder = Folder ("C:\\Users\\Данила\\Documents\\PhotoBook")
     // get all files in the input folder
     var fileList = inputFolder.getFiles("*.jpg");`

Comment: ...and then add main body to loop `for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    open(fileList[i]);
    var fname = app.activeDocument.name.replace(/\s+/g, '_').replace(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/g, '$1_$2').toLowerCase();}`